# Displays are misaligned, mouse clicks offset

Tags: kubuntu

Ubuntu version 22.04 LTS, Plasma 5.24.6, three monitor setup.

My PC crashed this morning and logged me out and when I logged back in the contents of the desktops were shifted by the width of the left-most monitor, while mouse clicks still land as if nothing happened. How can this be fixed, or do I have to reinstall?

Like the mouse clicks, on a screen capture of all monitors, the draw is perfectly correct.

More notes:

The photo is of my center display: the desktop appears to be offset to the right by the width of the first monitor. The mouse pointer is still clicking as if the display was correctly drawn.

According to settings, the monitors are in the correct L-R order.

The task bar hasn't been dragged to that position: the desktops are shifted.

[image: photo]

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you mean by misaligned.  However, it looks as though your monitors needs to be dragged in that display setting to the right locations.  From your display image you have the Acer to the left, but it needs to be in the middle according to the image you posted.

Comment: No, the monitors aligned as they are is a second issue. If you look at the second image, that's one monitor: note that the task bar is sitting at about 3/4 of the way from the left to the right edge of the screen. The mouse pointer is still clicking as if the display was correctly drawn.

Comment: The desktops appear to be shifted to the right by the width of the first monitor.

Comment: That is usually because the monitors need to be readjusted in the Monitor settings by dragging them and resetting them in the correct locations.  They do allow overlapping, so you have to be careful when you are dragging them.

Comment: The monitors are already in their correct positions as far as settings are concerned. Only their contents are shifted. Forcing a log-off or even just blanking the screens fixes the problem. I'm trying to figure out the cause so I can address it.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me that should be filed with the developers if forcing a logoff or just blanking the screen fixes the issues.  See:  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kubuntu/Bugs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I was obliged to reinstall the OS. Haven't had the problem since.